# Unable to get Dynamic templates working in Angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to write a small angular app that has 3 modes. QA, Production and Sandbox. QA is something that has multiple buttons, so that user cans select any value he wants and populates "myModel". The other 2 modes, Production and sandbox  have buttons beside them to apply the previously selected Qa value(from myModel, using the sync function).

I am using different templates for QA (multiple buttons) and Production,Sandbox(single button to sync from QA- mymodel.) I am able to render the QA/Production template fine but the QA template(listof buttons) doesn't show up at all.

I am guessing there is something wrong wiht the way compile is happenign for the list of buttons.

> Please see my code at : http://jsbin.com/sutipo/1/watch?html,js,output

HTML & Directive I am using to dynamically pickup templates is below :

```
    <tr>
        <td> <strong>Production : </strong>  </td>
        <td> {{types.production.text}} </td>
        <td><app-typedisplay env="production" status="non-base"></app-typedisplay></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <strong>SandBox : </strong>  </td>
        <td> {{types.sandbox.text}}  </td>
        <td><app-typedisplay env="sandbox" status="non-base"></app-typedisplay></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>QA : </strong>
        <td> {{types.qa.text}}  </td>
        <td><app-typedisplay env="qa" status="base"></app-typedisplay></td>
    </tr>
```

And the directive :

```
app.directive('appTypedisplay', function ($compile) {

    var getTemplate = function (content) {
        var template = '';
        var base = "<button type='button' class='btn btn-default' " +
            "ng-class='{active: option.text == model.text}'" +
            "ng-repeat='option in options' " +
            "ng-click='activate(option)'>{{option.text}} " +
            "</button>";

        var non_base = "<td> <button " +
            'ng-click=\'sync("' + content.env + '")\'>' +
            "Sync to " + content.env + "</button> </td>";

        switch (content.status) {
            case 'base':
                template = base;
                break;
            case 'non-base':
                template = non_base;
                break;
        }

        return template;
    };

    var linker = function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.html(getTemplate(attrs));
        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            model: '=',
            options: '=',
            env: '='
        },
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.activate = function (option) {
                $scope.model = option;
            };
        },
        link: linker
    };
});
```

Angular newbie here, Can some one please help me understand why the list of buttons template is not being compiled properly?

expected output should look like something below :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined some attributes to pass into your directive's isolate scope, but never passed the actual model references:

```
<app-typedisplay env="qa" status="base" options="options" model="myModel"></app-typedisplay>
```

The isolate scope directive doesn't know anything about a parent's scope, so all data used must be explicitly passed in through attributes

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was able to pass the options and model to populate the buttons. I have one question. How can I make the Scope functions accessible, as I cannot pass functions through attributes.

Comment: You can pass them through attributes by using the `&` instead of `=`. You could also pass the function reference using the `=` still. You may want to read up on the different options for passing attributes. Then there's always the option of just not using an isolate scope, and allowing the model data to pass into the directive.

Comment: Thanks Austin, Very helpful. I did read up on different options for passing attributes and was able to resolve the issues.